# 3D tool for a visual analysis

Tags: 3d, analysis, visualisation, 3d-model

Given a 3D mesh I need to visualize and analyze properties and elements generated from the object such as:

- tensors
- coplanar/similar elements ( coplanar faces, aligned vertices, etc etc, 3D geometry basically )
- normals
- grouped faces

I'm especially interested in tensors and in any property that I can use to simplify and understand some linear algebra computation.

Do you know about any tool like the one I'm looking for ?

Comment: Can you explain why you think this might be a GIS problem?

Comment: @BradHards it's about topology

Comment: This book may interest you: Joseph O'Rourke 1998, Computational Geometry in C, http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html

Comment: @markusN I appreciate that but I don't care about manipulating the mesh, I'm interested only in studying its properties

Comment: no one with this problem ? no one needs to take a look at mesh properties ?